# Why would my ATSAM4E not reset even if I power cycle?

Tags: microcontroller, atmel, flash

I am using an Atmel SAM4E_EK board with SAM4E16E microcontroller. Recently the board started with the following quirk:

When I upload a program using Atmel-ICE over SWD, the chip resets and runs my code without problems. However when I push the reset button or power cycle, the MCU just freezes, doing nothing at all.

What may be the problem with the MCU? I suspect some problems with the on board flash.

EDIT: I got a second board. It was working normally until I accidentally pressed the reset button while flashing a new binary. Now the second board behaves exactly the same way.

Comment: Could this be a brownout problem? Make sure your BOD is enabled.

Comment: No, the voltage in my office is fairly well regulated. Besides, I got another board and used it with the same power plug and power supply, it resets normally.

Comment: I meant the Brownout-Detect that's present on-chip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really an answer, but I resolved the problem. I built and flashed one of the examples that come with Atmel Studio. After it was built and flashed successfully, all later flashes and resets worked properly.